# Converting a rails+nginx webapp to use HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

I am currently doing a web app for my company. Suddenly, we were told to change the server to https. We are using rails + nginx server.

I have made changes to the nginx conf as I read in the nginx wiki:

```
listen 443;
ssl on;
ssl_certficate .......;
ssl_key ....;
```

Upon further research, I came to know that I have to make certain changes in the rails . So I installed the `ssl_requirement` plugin, and added these lines in the config file:

```
"include SslRequirement"
```

in my application.rb file. So when I start my server and type the host name, I either get "`a plain HTTP request sent`" or "`This page isnt redirecting properly`".

Please tell me where I am going wrong here.

PS : I have to make the entire application https.

Answer (score 0):

Test your application first by redirecting one of the methods in your application.... as like...
In controller.rb

```
ssl_required :action_name
```

thanks.....